# Getting total of each occurance of a number in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in a table which has integer values. I am trying find total number of times each number appears in that column. I can do it manually but than I would have to write select for each number.

```
select Count(Distinct IdStatus) from t_Class 
select COUNT(IdStatus) from t_Class  where IdStatus=50
select COUNT(IdStatus) from t_Class  where IdStatus=100
```

How can get the select statment which will get total of how many times each number appears in that column. 
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that using `group by`:

```
select IdStatus, COUNT(*) as CountOfStatus
from t_Class  
group by IdStatus
```

Comment: Nice, Mitch.  You beat me to it!

Answer (score 1):

Mitch's answer will work fine as long as you do not have any rows where IdStatus is NULL.  If you have (or might have) rows where IdStatus is NULL, then you should do

```
select IdStatus,  COUNT(*) as CountOfStatus
from t_Class  
group by IdStatus
```

`Count(*)` will count every row, `Count(<expression>)` only counts rows where  is not NULL.